# How to build Apple's Metal-cpp example using CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake, metal

Recently, Apple has released a library to use Metal directly using C++. The example that I've found online (https://github.com/moritzhof/metal-cpp-examples), works if I copy the source code and follow the steps outlined by Apple (https://developer.apple.com/metal/cpp/) in Xcode. I don't use the included Xcode project files, to avoid any "hidden" settings.

Now I'm trying to get the same example to build using CMake, with this CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(HelloWorld)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/metal-cpp)

set(SOURCE_FILES metal-cpp-test/main.cpp metal-cpp-test/metal_adder.cpp)
add_executable(program ${SOURCE_FILES})

# specify which libraries to connect
# target_link_libraries(program ${METAL})
# target_link_libraries(program ${FOUNDATION})
# target_link_libraries(program ${QUARTZCORE})

find_library(METAL Metal)
find_library(FOUNDATION Foundation)
find_library(QUARTZCORE QuartzCore)

target_link_libraries(program stdc++ "-framework Metal" "-framework Foundation" "-framework QuartzCore" objc)
```

It compiles successfully, but the line

```
auto lib = _device->newDefaultLibrary();
```

Now seems to return a null-ptr. Any idea what the reason for this could be and how to solve this?

Comment: Is your GPU _device object initialized?

Comment: I believe so, I can get the name for example. But like I said, the exact same code works if I configure it as an Xcode-project, so I expect the problem to be somewhere in the settings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All **.metal** files in an Xcode project that builds an application are compiled and built into a single **default library**.

`_device->newDefaultLibrary()` return a new library object that contains the functions from the **default library**. This method returns nil if the **default library** cannot be found.

Since you are not using Xcode, you should [manually compile](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/libraries/building_a_library_with_metal_s_command-line_tools?language=objc) Metal Shading Language source code and build a Metal library.

Then, at runtime, call the `newLibrary(filePath, &error)` method to retrieve and access your library as a `MTL::Library` object.

```
NS::String* filePath = NS::String::string("The full file path to a .metallib file", NS::UTF8StringEncoding);
NS::Error* error;
auto library =_device->newLibrary(filePath, &error);
if(error)
{
                    
}
```

Comment: Ah thank you, that was the issue indeed. I'm now using newLibrary(const NS::String* source, const MTL::CompileOptions* options, NS::Error** error), to build from string and it seems to be working. Slightly confusing naming though, as I initially thought the default library was some sort of system library.